# How do you create one pivot table per worksheet using the Import Excel module?

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I'm trying to create one pivot table for each worksheet that is created.
The problem that I am encountering is that Excel throws an error and says the first pivot table is unreadable and unrecoverable, and that sheet is now blank.

I'm intentionally not specifying what data to pivot on in this code, I just want to see that the pivot tables are being created and linked correctly.

```
function createDT()
{
    ###Creating a new DataTable###
    $tempTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
   
    ##Creating Columns for DataTable##
    $query = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“query”)
    $sheetName = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“sheetName”)
    $format = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“format”)
    $pivotRow = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“pivotRow”)
    $pivotData = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn(“pivotData”)
           
    ###Adding Columns for DataTable###
    $tempTable.columns.Add($query)
    $tempTable.columns.Add($sheetName)
    $tempTable.columns.Add($format)
    $tempTable.columns.Add($pivotRow)
    $tempTable.columns.Add($pivotData)
       
    return ,$tempTable
}

###Create a new DataTable###
[System.Data.DataTable]$dTable = createDT

###Add a row to DataTable###
$row = $dTable.NewRow()
$row[“query”] = “SELECT * FROM exampletable”
$row[“sheetName”] = “exampletable”
$row[“format”] = "Medium2"
$row[“pivotRow”] = "row"
$row[“pivotData”] = "data"
$dTable.rows.Add($row)
###Add a row to DataTable###
$row = $dTable.NewRow()
$row[“query”] = “SELECT * FROM exampletable2”
$row[“sheetName”] = “exampletable2”
$row[“format”] = "Medium2"
$row[“pivotRow”] = "row"
$row[“pivotData”] = "data"
$dTable.rows.Add($row)

 ###Length of the data table###
 $dtLength = $dTable.Rows.Count

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dtLength; $i++)
{

  
    $pvTable = New-PivotTableDefinition -PivotTableName $i -SourceWorksheet $dTable.sheetName[$i] 
    

    Invoke-SQLCmd -query $dTable.query[$i] -database $dbname -serverinstance $ServerName | Export-Excel -workSheetName $dTable.sheetName[$i] -TableStyle $dTable.format[$i] -BoldTopRow -path $destination -AutoSize -AutoFilter -PivotTableDefinition $pvTable 

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have found a workaround for now...
When I remove the `-TableStyle $dTable.format[$i]`
the error disappears and the pivot tables work